# Ion-item rendering incorrectly when it picks up 2 icons

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a way to display the right chevron on a list item with a star icon?

**Code so far:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" href="#" ng-repeat="item in reviewList" >
        <img src="img/ionic.png">
        <i class="icon ion-star energized" ng-repeat="n in [] | range: item.rating"></i><i class="icon ion-star dark" ng-repeat="n in [] | range: 5-item.rating"></i>
        <strong>{{item.title}}</strong>
        <p>{{item.review}}</p>
        <p>{{item.date}} by {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
    </ion-item>
<ion-list>
```

**This is what I am currently getting:**

Before adding `item-icon-right` to `ion-tem` tag and `<i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>`, everything looks fine. I just want to add the `ion-chevron-right`.

[image]

After adding `item-icon-right` to `ion-tem` tag and `<i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>`, everything looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by doing the following:

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item item item-avatar item-icon-right" href="#" ng-repeat="item in reviewList" >
            <img src="img/ionic.png">
            <p>
                <span ng-repeat="n in [] | range: item.rating" class="energized">&#9733;</span><span ng-repeat="n in [] | range: 5-item.rating" class="dark">&#9733;</span>
                <strong>{{item.title}}</strong>
                <p>{{item.review}}</p>
                <p><small>{{item.date}} by {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</small></p>
            <p>
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i> 
        </ion-item>
    <ion-list>
```